# Define a linear map $f:\mathbb{C^2}\to \mathbb{C^2}$ such that $\mathrm{Ker}(f)=V$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $V=\{(z,w) : 2z - w = 0\} \in \mathbb{C^2}$

The exercise asks me to find a basis of $V$ as a $\mathbb{C}$-vector space:

$B_V=\{(1,2)\}$

Then it asks me to define a $\mathbb{C}$-linear map $f:\mathbb{C^2}\to \mathbb{C^2}$ such that $\mathrm{Ker}(f)=V$:

$$M(f)=
        \begin{pmatrix}
        a & c  \\
        b & d 
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

$f(x,y)= M(x,y)^{T}=(ax+cy,bx+dy)^{T}$

$f(1,2)=(0,0),$ so $a+2c=b+2d=0,$ then 
$$M(f)=
        \begin{pmatrix}
        -2c & c  \\
        -2d & d 
        \end{pmatrix}
$$ where the columns are the vectors of $\mathrm{Im}(f)$

I put $c=d=1$ so 
$$M(f)=
        \begin{pmatrix}
        -2 & 1  \\
        -2 & 1 
        \end{pmatrix}
$$ should be the matrix associated to $f$.

Is it the right way?

Then the exercise asks me to find a basis of $V$ as a $\mathbb{R}$-vector space:

$B_V=\{(1,2),(i,2i)\}$ (I am not sure about this one).

Then it asks me to define a $\mathbb{R}$-linear map $f:\mathbb{C^2}\to \mathbb{C^2}$ such that $\mathrm{Ker}(f)=V$, and I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: It seems good, but a little bit complicated, why don't you just define $f(z,w) = 2z-w$? Then ask yourself, is $f$ also $\mathbb R$-linear?

Comment: @flawr I don't understand, by defining $f$ in that way $\ker(f)$ is not $V$, am I right?

Comment: @flawr In your example $f$ is $\mathbb{C}^2 \to \mathbb{C}$ function. Maybe $f(z,w) = (2z-w,0)$ would do the trick.

Comment: @Stefan4024 Oh, you're right, I forgot about the second component!

Comment: I have another question: the matrix associated to a whatever $f:\mathbb{C^2}\to \mathbb{C^2}$ where $\mathbb{C^2}$ is a $\mathbb{R}$-vector space is a non-square matrix?

Answer (score 1):

How about completing the base of $V$ to a base of $\mathbb{C}^2$? For example $\beta = \{(1,2),(0,1)\}$ is one. Then write element of $\mathbb{C}^2$ as linear combination of that base to get $(x,y) = x\cdot (1,2) + (y-2x)\cdot (0,1)$.

Then use the fact that $f(1,2) = (0,0)$ and so the function is completely defined by the action of $f$ on the second element of the base. So you have:

$$f(x,y) = f(x\cdot (1,2) + (y-2x)\cdot (0,1)) = (y-2x)f(0,1)$$

Now you can send $f(0,1)$ to any non-zero element of $\mathbb{C}^2$ and you will have a map $f$ that satisfies the conditions. Now can you do the same for $\mathbb{R}^2$?